# Extract query from Google Sheets Filter View

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to extract the query that essentially exists inside of a Filter view? i.e. if I've set up a FV that specifies Column 1 > 5, Column 3 = "yes", etc., it would be great to be able to extract that query in some form (or at least "see it" in some way).

Comment: One more try: A filter view is essentially a way to build a query. Is there a way to access that query, for example to error check it or perhaps to use it in a script? I have spent hours but don't have the faintest lead towards an answer, except if I just want to assume the answer is no. Hence I am here. Thank you. For the record, I think this is a good question and wouldn't mind some upvotes, I can't upvote anyone else as-is ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the FILTER function:

```
=filter(A:E, C:C="YES")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess my question wasnt clear. If I've already set up a filter view (or someone else has) and I want to see the query that IS the filter view (I want to see what they sorted, filtered, etc), is there any way to do that? For a complex filter view, it's a pretty big disadvantage not being able to see what it is doing. A filter can appear to do the same thing as a filter view, except it's not editable.

Comment: I should have led with: A filter can appear to do the same thing as a filter view, except it's not editable. So it's entirely different. Thanks though